How to configure bspwm in WSL2 Ubuntu?
I'm trying to install bspwm in WSL2 Ubuntu-24.04 LTS, and each time I run bspwm, it says "Another window manager is already running", and I don't have any other window manager installed. What is the problem? xclock runs alright.
Does that mean that WSL does not support bspwm? I am completely new to linux and I canot find any guide about installing bspwm on WSL.

The problem is not specific to bspwm but to window managers in general. see e.g. https://aymen-furter.medium.com/running-a-window-manager-on-top-of-wsl2-a82bdc8f3c88

alright thanks! I'll just switch to VMware then
